# With django forms how to organize fields in multiple columns?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
  row_1 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
  row_2_col_1 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
  row_2_col_2 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)

  def render_form(request):
    form = MyForm()
    # render form
```

What should be my template so that final html is something like

```
<table>
<tr> row_1 field.. </tr>
<tr>
  <td> row_2_col_1 field.. </td>
  <td> row_2_col_2 field.. </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: any reason you'd do this with HTML rather than CSS?  Do your form inputs actually represent tabular data or do you just want them displayed that way?

Comment: My form inputs are tabular. How can do it with CSS?

Comment: If your form inputs represent tabular data then you should output them in a table.  Otherwise you should be outputting them as `ul`(s) and then you could create the multiple columns by using something like `ul { position: relative; overflow: hidden; } ul li { width: 50%; float:left; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've passed the table to the form in the request you just need to use Django template mark up:

```
<table>
<tr>{{ table.row_1 }}</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{ table.row_2_col_1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ table.row_2_col_2 }}</td>
</tr>
```